# How to construct a complicated function pointer without typedef in C++？

Tags: c++, pointers

```
auto func(int (*(*pf)(int *)), int *p) -> int *(*)(int *)
{
    cout << *(pf(p)) << endl;
    return pf;
}//C++11 Standard

int *(*func2(int (*(*pf)(int *)), int *p))(int *)
{
    cout << *(pf(p)) << endl;
    return pf;
}//Before C++11 standard
```

This is a function that takes an int function pointer and an int pointer as it's parameter, and will return a int function pointer.

How to create a pointer for this function?

Comment: Why is your indentation so bizarre? And why not a typedef or two so that your code is readable?

Comment: Although I am convinced that it is possible to write such a pointer  without a `typedef` I would never try this.

Comment: `std::function` or using typedefs allow for a much more readable code.

Comment: But I wanna learn how to do that.

Comment: Well, you wanna read the relevant chapter in K & R. Applies to C++ too.

Comment: Well I always just replace the function name with a `(*ptr_name)` and be done with it. So `int *(*(*f_ptr)(int(*(*pf)(int *)), int *p))(int *)=func2;` would declare a pointer in your case.

Comment: @YANG oh wait, do you mean a pointer to this function or a pointer that you can pass to this function?

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T> using type=T;

template<class R, class...Args>
using sig=R(Args...);

typedef sig<int *(*)(int *) ,int (*(*)(int *)), int *>* pFun;
```

or

```
typedef
type<int *(*(int (*(*)(int *)), int *))(int *)>* pFun2;
```

Apply recursively, use `using` and/or `typedef` liberally.

In C++03, you can have `ptr_to<X>::type` which works.

Naturally this is silly, as you would really want to solve the problem with meaningful type names, rather than using template tomfoolery or wrangle K&R syntax.